# Should I create new NSURLSessionTask after handling HTTP error?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsurlsessionuploadtask

In my Xamarin.iOS app, I want to retry an upload after a failure due to http error.

But I'm not sure how to implement.

I was thinking I should just keep creating a new task every time it completes with an http error?
Is this the correct way to implement?

NSUrlSessionTaskDelegate:

```
    public async override void DidCompleteWithError(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionTask task, NSError error)
    {
        if (task.Response != null)
        {
            if (task.Response is NSHttpUrlResponse httpResponse)
            {
                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == 200)
                {
                    //some clean up logic here
                }
                else if (httpResponse.StatusCode > 400 && httpResponse.StatusCode < 500)
                {
                    //what to do to upload again?
                }
                else
                {
                    var applicationException = new ApplicationException("Server returned 500");
                    Crashes.TrackError(applicationException);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

AppDelegate:

```
    public NSUrlSession InitBackgroundSession()
    {
        string identifier = "com.uba.BookingUploadBackgroundSession";
        INSUrlSessionDelegate backgroundUploadSessionDelegate = new BackgroundBookingUploadSessionDelegate();

        using (var config = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.CreateBackgroundSessionConfiguration(identifier))
        {
            config.HttpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 4;
            config.TimeoutIntervalForResource = 300.0; //5mins
            return NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(config, backgroundUploadSessionDelegate, new NSOperationQueue());
        }
    }

    //gets called when user taps Submit from ViewController
    public void UploadFile(BookingDTO newBookingDTO)
    {
        //logic to create NSMutableUrlRequest omitted

        var uploadTask = session.CreateUploadTask(request, NSUrl.FromFilename(filename));
        uploadTask.TaskDescription = newBookingDTO.ClientId;  //we need the booking id so we can delete it later
        uploadTask.Resume();
     }
```

I'll accept any answer in C#, Swift or Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NSURLSessionTask** has four different states.As shown in the following image.
[image]

When the upload finished.Whether success or fail,the states will become **Completed**.And the property **CurrentRequest** will be null. You can only handle the Response of the task.So .I think you can use the same session but have to create a new task.You can use the **Notification** to send message.

> NSUrlSessionTaskDelegate:

```
public async override void DidCompleteWithError(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionTask task, NSError error)
{
    if (task.Response != null)
    {
        if (task.Response is NSHttpUrlResponse httpResponse)
        {
            if (httpResponse.StatusCode == 200)
            {
                //some clean up logic here
            }
            else if (httpResponse.StatusCode > 400 && httpResponse.StatusCode < 500)
            {
                //send notification here 
                NSNotification notification = NSNotification.FromName("UploadFail",null,null);
                NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotification(notification); 

            }
            else
            {
                var applicationException = new ApplicationException("Server returned 500");
                Crashes.TrackError(applicationException);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in AppDelegate.cs , add the notification in method **FinishedLaunching**

```
 NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this,new Selector("UploadAgain"),new NSString("UploadFail"),null);

[Export("UploadAgain")]
void UploadAgain()
{
   //call your upload code here
}
```

Comment: You're missing some common error cases there.  For example, the connection could fail with a timeout (error != nil) even after you get a 200 code from the server, and you probably want to retry in that case.  And you may want to ask for a new password if you get a 401.